# Why can't other users see the files I post to Samba share?

Tags: samba, greyhole, amahi

I run an Amahi server that uses samba and greyhole for file sharing. 
When I copy a file to one of the shares, others cannot see it. If another user adds a file to a share, they succeed, but after refresh, they can no longer see the file. The file is in the share and I can see it.

All files created more than 4-6 weeks ago can be seen by anyone. I haven't been able to determine what might have changed. Last reboot was 60 days ago

This feels like a samba-related problem but I cannot pinpoint it.

Things I've checked:
Linux permissions - all files (/var/hda/files/tv/)are owned by my amahi/linux user (not root) and the users group. All users are in the same group. That group has RW permissions.
Samba Permissions - share uses user permissions users have RW.
create mask is 0755

I ran greyhole fsck against the TV path with no change

Here are the current permissions of two files:

```
    Failed file ( as root)
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gmartin users 205775332 May  4 20:48 /var/hda/files/drives/drive1/gh/TV/SomeShow/SomeShow-S01E02.avi

Successful file (as wdtv)
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gmartin users 257642672 Apr 13 21:55 /var/hda/files/drives/Drive6/gh/TV/SomeShow/SomeShow-S01E05.avi
```

Info:
Fedora Core 23
Amahi 9.0.0-1
Core 7.0.0-1
samba v 4.3.12
greyhole 0.10.6

Clients: Win10 (1703), WDTV Live

Comment: If you create a second user yourself, are you able to recreate the problems yourself, what OS are the clients running?  The file share server is running Fedora (you do know that's out of date right?)

Comment: I'll try a new user, but this is affecting all currents users. Clients are Win10 and a WDTV Live (Added above). (Server OS will be refreshed this fall)

Comment: Please verify the outputtof `ls -lsa` on the directory you copied a new file into.to verify ownership and permissions on that file is correct after being copied. The only other thing I could think of would be the share directory on the clients may need to be refreshed, as I don't believe they auto-refresh.  Also, check the samba logs of the server and client(s).

Comment: Ran `ls -lsa` and the ownership for good and bad files are identical as are permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greyhole works by moving the real file you add to your shares onto other drive(s). Thus, once Greyhole move the file and leave behind a symlink in `/var/hda/files/`, if your users don't have the permissions required to access the file that is now on another drive, those users will be able to read the symlink, but not its target, and thus the file will be hidden by Samba.

Login as a problematic user (using SSH; use `sudo` if needed), and go look at a symlink in `/var/hda/files/` that this user doesn't see on the share. Look at the target of that symlink, and try to access that file. You'll most probably find that you can't. You probably need to `chown/chmod -R` all your data drives (are those still mounted in `/var/hda/drives`?)

**Update:**
I added a page on the wiki about this, with examples: https://github.com/gboudreau/Greyhole/wiki/Permissions-Data-Drives

**Update 2:** Try this:

```
$ chown -R gb:users /var/hda/files/drives/*
$ find /var/hda/files/drives/* -type d -exec chmod 775 "{}" \; # Permissions for directories
$ find /var/hda/files/drives/* -type f -exec chmod 664 "{}" \; # Permissions for files
```

Change `gb:users`, `775` and `664` as needed.

Comment: Indeed, one of the users cannot access the "bad" files. What permissions should I reset (chown/chmod) to? I'll add two examples of a working and non-working file to the question.

Comment: Nevermind - I'm reading the wiki page.  sorry

Comment: I ran 
`$ chown -R gmartin:users /var/hda/drive/*/gh

$ chmod -R g+w /var/hda/drives/*/gh` and the test user still gets `permissions denied`

Comment: `chmod -R g+w` was probably not enough for you, since your users can't even "see" the files. You need to give the group `rwx` (or `r-x`) access. See my updated answer for examples.

Comment: Still no luck here. Using one of the user accounts, I still cannot access new files.  Weird that in one directory I have two new files that cannot be seen and many that can.

Comment: Using SSH, login as that user account, and try to `cd` into the problematic folder (on a data drive), one level at a time: `cd /var/`; `cd hda`; `cd files`; ..., ; `cd drive1`, ..., `cd SomeShow`. That will show you at what level the problematic permissions are.

Comment: That found it! Odd thing is that both drive mounts have different issues. drive1 was 700 at that level.  Drive6 was owned by root:root.